# Evaluating $\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{\arctan{x}}{1+x}\ln{\left(\frac{1+x^2}{2}\right)}dx$

Tags: integration

This is a nice problem. I am trying to use nice methods to solve this integral, But I failed.

$$\int_{-1}^{1}\dfrac{\arctan{x}}{1+x}\ln{\left(\dfrac{1+x^2}{2}\right)}dx, $$

where  $\arctan{x}=\tan^{-1}{x}$

mark: this integral is my favorite one. Thanks to whoever has nice methods.

I have proved the following:

$$\int_{-1}^{1}\dfrac{\arctan{x}}{1+x}\ln{\left(\dfrac{1+x^2}{2}\right)}dx=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{2^{n-1}H^2_{n-1}}{nC_{2n}^{n}}=\dfrac{\pi^3}{96}$$

where $$C_{m}^{n}=\dfrac{m}{(m-n)!n!},H_{n}=1+\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{3}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{n}$$

I also have got a few by-products 
$$\int_{-1}^{1}\dfrac{\arctan{x}}{1+x}\ln{\left(\dfrac{1+x^2}{2}\right)}dx=-I_{1}-2I_{2}$$

where $$I_{1}=\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{\ln{(1-x^2)}}{1+x^2}\ln{\left(\dfrac{1+x^2}{2}\right)}dx=\dfrac{\pi}{4}\ln^2{2}+\dfrac{\pi^3}{32}-2K\times\ln{2}$$

and
$$I_{2}=\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{x\arctan{x}}{1+x^2}\ln{(1-x^2)}dx=-\dfrac{\pi^3}{48}-\dfrac{\pi}{8}\ln^2{2}+K\times\ln{2}$$

and same methods,I have follow integral
$$\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{\ln{(1-x^4)}\ln{x}}{1+x^2}dx=\dfrac{\pi^3}{16}-3K\times\ln{2}$$
where $ K $ denotes Catalan's Constant.

Comment: As a quick thought, for $I_1 $ have you tried expanding the two logarithms using their Maclaurin series and then evaluating $ \int\limits_0^1 \frac{x^n}{1 + x^2} \ dx $?

Comment: Looking at the [revision history](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/407420/revisions), @Arthur, it was not the OP who removed the words...

Comment: @J.M. You're absolutely right; I was perhaps a bit too hasty in my comment.  My apologies to the OP for intimating any wrongdoing on his/her part.

Comment: @math110: I tried to improve you post. Make sure this is what you want to ask.

Comment: A very simple & elegant solution may be found in [this solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4384973).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here is a solution that only uses complex analysis:

Let $\epsilon$ > 0 and consider the truncated integral

$$ I_{\epsilon} = \int_{-1+\epsilon}^{1} \frac{\arctan x}{x+1} \log\left( \frac{1+x^2}{2} \right) \, dx. $$

By using the formula

$$ \arctan x = \frac{1}{2i} \log \left( \frac{1 + ix}{1 - ix} \right) = \frac{1}{2i} \left\{ \log \left( \frac{1+ix}{\sqrt{2}} \right) - \log \left( \frac{1-ix}{\sqrt{2}} \right) \right\}, $$

it follows that

$$ I_{\epsilon} = \Im \int_{-1+\epsilon}^{1} \frac{1}{x+1} \log^{2} \left( \frac{1+ix}{\sqrt{2}} \right) \, dx. $$

Now let $\omega = e^{i\pi/4}$ and make the change of variable $z = \frac{1+ix}{\sqrt{2}}$ to obtain

$$ I_{\epsilon} = \Im \int_{L_{\epsilon}} \frac{\log^2 z}{z - \bar{\omega}} \, dz, $$

where $L_{\epsilon}$ is the line segment joining from $\bar{\omega}_{\epsilon} := \bar{\omega} + \frac{i\epsilon}{\sqrt{2}}$ to $\omega$. Now we tweak this contour of integration according to the following picture:

[image]

That is, we first draw a clockwise circular arc $\gamma_{\epsilon}$ centered at $\bar{\omega}$ joining from $\bar{\omega}_{\epsilon}$ to some points on the unit circle, and draw a counter-clockwise circular arc $\Gamma_{\epsilon}$ joining from the endpoint of $\gamma_{\epsilon}$ to $\omega$. Then

$$ I_{\epsilon} = \Im \int_{\gamma_{\epsilon}} \frac{\log^2 z}{z - \bar{\omega}} \, dz + \Im \int_{\Gamma_{\epsilon}} \frac{\log^2 z}{z - \bar{\omega}} \, dz =: J_{\epsilon} + K_{\epsilon}. $$

It is easy to check that as $\epsilon \to 0^{+}$, the central angle of $\gamma_{\epsilon}$ converges to $\pi / 4$. Since $\gamma_{\epsilon}$ winds $\bar{\omega}$ clockwise, we have

$$ \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}} J_{\epsilon} = \Im \left( -\frac{i \pi}{4} \mathrm{Res}_{z=\bar{\omega}} \frac{\log^2 z}{z - \bar{\omega}} \right) = \frac{3}{2} \frac{\pi^3}{96}. $$

Also, by applying the change of variable $z = e^{i\theta}$,

$$ K_{\epsilon} = -\Re \int_{-\frac{\pi}{4}+o(1)}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\theta^2}{1 - \bar{\omega}e^{-i\theta}} \, d\theta = \int_{-\frac{\pi}{4}+o(1)}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\theta^2}{2} \, d\theta. $$

Thus taking $\epsilon \to 0^{+}$, we have

$$ \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}} K_{\epsilon} = - \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \theta^2 \, d\theta = - \frac{1}{2} \frac{\pi^3}{96}. $$

Combining these results, we have

$$ \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{\arctan x}{x+1} \log \left( \frac{x^2 + 1}{2} \right) \, dx = \frac{\pi^3}{96}. $$

The same technique shows that

$$ \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{\arctan (t x)}{x+1} \log \left( \frac{1 + x^2 t^2}{1 + t^2} \right) \, dx = \frac{2}{3} \arctan^{3} t, \quad t \in \Bbb{R} .$$

Comment: What does $ J $ represent? Also, how does the third equality for $ I_e $ follow? I understand that it is equal to $ \frac{1}{2i}\int_{-1 + \epsilon}^1 \frac{1}{x + 1}\left(\ln^2\left(\frac{1 + ix}{\sqrt{2}}\right) - \ln^2\left(\frac{1 - ix}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right) \ dx $.

Comment: @JonClaus, do you mean $\Im$? This is the symbol representing the imaginary part function $$ \Im : z = x + iy \mapsto y. $$ Now you can derive the third identity by recalling that $$ \Im (z) = \frac{z - \bar{z}}{2i} \quad \text{and} \quad \overline{\log z} = \log \bar{z} $$ for the logarithm function $\log$ with the branch cut $(-\infty, 0]$.

Comment: Yes, I misread the Imaginary Part function. It appears to be rendered slightly differently from what I've seen before. All clear now.

Comment: Bravo!  Beautiful work. (+!)

Answer (score 4):

FWIW, here's Maple:

```
> f:= arctan(x)/(1+x)*ln((1+x^2)/2);
> int(f, x=-1..1);
```

$$ {\frac {7}{64}}\,{\pi }^{3}-{\frac {5}{16}}\,\pi \, \left( \ln 
 \left( 2 \right)  \right) ^{2}-\ln  \left( 2 \right) {\it Catalan}+1/
2\, \left( \ln  \left( 1-i \right)  \right) ^{2}\pi -1/2\,i \left( 
\ln  \left( 1+i \right)  \right) ^{2}\ln  \left( 2 \right) +\ln 
 \left( 1+i \right) {\it Catalan}+1/2\, \left( \ln  \left( 1+i
 \right)  \right) ^{2}\pi -i{\it polylog} \left( 3,-i \right) +i{\it 
polylog} \left( 3,i \right) +1/2\,i \left( \ln  \left( 1-i \right) 
 \right) ^{2}\ln  \left( 2 \right) -1/2\,i \left( \ln  \left( 1-i
 \right)  \right) ^{3}-1/48\,i\ln  \left( 1+i \right) {\pi }^{2}+1/2\,
i \left( \ln  \left( 1+i \right)  \right) ^{3}+\ln  \left( 1-i
 \right) {\it Catalan}+1/48\,i\ln  \left( 1-i \right) {\pi }^{2}
$$

```
> simplify(%);
```

$$ \frac{\pi^3}{96}
$$

I don't know if that qualifies as "nice", but it's certainly easy.

Comment: Wow, Maple can do that? I am amazed...

Answer (score 4):

Splitting the integral at $x=0$, letting $x\mapsto -x$ in the first integral and then adding it to the second one, we arrive at
$$\int_{-1}^1\frac{\arctan(x)\log((1+x^2)/2)}{1+x}\textrm{d}x=2\int_0^1 \frac{x\arctan(x) \log(2/(1+x^2))}{1-x^2}\textrm{d}x=\frac{\pi^3}{96},$$
where the last integral is extracted [in this solution magically exploiting the symmetry of a triple integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4384973).

**End of story**

Comment: Fantastica as always!! (+1)