# Another math contest problem: $\int_0^{\frac{\ln^22}4}\,\frac{\arccos\frac{\exp\sqrt x}{\sqrt2}}{1-\exp\sqrt{4\,x}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, contest-math, closed-form

> Prove:
>   $$
> {\Large\int_{0}^{\ln^{2}\left(2\right) \over4}}\,
> \frac{\arccos\left(\vphantom{\huge A}
> {\exp\left(\vphantom{\large A}\sqrt{x\,}\right)
> \over
> \sqrt{\vphantom{\large A}2\,}}\right)}
> {1-\exp\left(\sqrt{4x\,}\,\right)}
> \,{\rm d}x
> =
> -\,\frac{\,\,\pi^{3}}{192}
> $$

I haven't solved it yet.

Comment: Is that $\ln(2)^ 2/4$ in the upper bound?

Comment: Mathematica 8 suggests, up to 100 digits, that $$ \int_{0}^{\frac{\log^{2}2}{4}} \frac{\arccos\left( \frac{\exp\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{2}} \right)}{1 - \exp\sqrt{4x}} \, dx = -\frac{\pi^{3}}{192}. $$
(Note that the domain of integral begins at 0.)

Comment: @Jean-Sébastien Yes.

Comment: @sos440 Thanks! I fixed the sign and the lower bound. I should be more careful when typing formulae.

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov makes more sense now. I was only saying that because $1>\ln^2(2)/4.$

Comment: @Jean-Sébastien Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: What contest is this from? Just curious.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With the substitution $x \mapsto \frac{1}{4}\log^{2}\left(\frac{2}{x^{2}+1}\right)$, it follows that

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\frac{\log^{2}2}{4}} \frac{\arccos\left( \frac{\exp\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{2}} \right)}{1 - \exp\sqrt{4x}} \, dx
&= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x \arctan x}{1 - x^{2}} \log\left(\frac{1+x^{2}}{2}\right) \, dx \\
&= -\frac{1}{2} \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{\arctan x}{1 + x} \log\left(\frac{1+x^{2}}{2}\right) \, dx.
\end{align*}

Now you can refer to [this solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407420/evaluating-int-11-frac-arctanx1x-ln-left-frac1x22-right/411763#411763).

---

Actually, I obtained this integral representation by applying the following chain of much human-friendly substitutions:

$$ \exp\sqrt{4x} = t, \qquad t = 2\cos^{2}u, \qquad x = \tan u $$

Comment: Have you already evaluated all possible integrals? ;)

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov, Sure I haven't :) I was just so lucky. You can prove my claim by giving me some integrals involving special functions (such as hypergeometric, Bessel, Airy, ...) and enjoying that I even don't know their definitions.

Comment: @sos440 I think you're being excessively modest.  I was going to ask you a question about your evaluation in the other post, but the answer came to me as I was typing the question.

Comment: Well, maybe I do have a question.  Why does $$I_{\epsilon} = J_{\epsilon} + K_{\epsilon}$$

necessarily imply that $$ \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{\arctan x}{1 + x} \log\left(\frac{1+x^{2}}{2}\right) \, dx= \lim_{ \epsilon \to 0} J_{\epsilon} +\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} K_{\epsilon} \ ?$$

Is is simply because $ \displaystyle\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{\arctan x}{1 + x} \log\left(\frac{1+x^{2}}{2}\right) \, dx$ converges?

Comment: @RandomVariable, That's because the integrand not only converges, but also is holomoprhic at $x = -1$ (and in particular, continuous.)

Answer (score 1):

use the residue theorem !

we first assume that :

$\exp\sqrt{x\,}=z$

then your formula turn out to be :

$
{\Large\int_{1}^{\sqrt{2}}}\,
\frac{\arccos\left(\vphantom{\huge A}
{z
\over
\sqrt{\vphantom{\large A}2\,}}\right)}
{1-z^2}
\,{\rm d}x
=
-\,\frac{\,\,\pi^{3}}{192}
$

the residue theorem gives ,

$
{\Large\int_{1}^{\sqrt{2}}}\,
\frac{\arccos\left(\vphantom{\ huge A}
{z
\over
\sqrt{\vphantom{\large A}2\,}}\right)}
{1-z^2}
\,{\rm d}x
=\frac{b\pi}{2}\cdot\frac{\arccos(1/\sqrt{2})}{2}\cdot\frac{\arccos(-1/\sqrt{2})}{-2}$$=-\frac{b\pi}{2}\cdot(\frac{\pi}{8})^2$

the last step is to calculate the radius :

$\frac{1}{b}=\frac{z}{2(Inz)^{'}}=$$z^{2}=z_{1}^{2}+z_{2}^{2}=\frac{3}{2}$$\Longrightarrow$$b=\frac{2}{3}$

then, your solution holds !