# Help on this integral $I=\int_0^1 \frac{x \arctan(x)}{1-x^2}\ln\left(\frac{2}{1+x^2}\right) dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$I=\int_0^1 \frac{x \arctan(x)}{1-x^2}\ln\left(\frac{2}{1+x^2}\right) dx$$

Here is my attempt

$\frac{x}{1-x^2}dx=-\frac{1}{2}d\ln(1-x^2)$, integration by part, we got
$$I=-\frac{1}{2}P-Q$$

Where $P=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x^2)\ln\left(\frac{1+x^2}{2}\right)}{1+x^2}dx$, and
$Q=\int_0^1 \frac{x\cdot\arctan(x)\cdot\ln(1-x^2)}{1+x^2}dx$

How to proceed then? or should I switch to other ways?

Comment: @KStarGamer yes, it is divergent at x=1

Comment: @KStarGamer Ah, yes, they are convergent. I didn't see that $\ln\left(\frac{1+x^2}{2}\right)$ factor, thank you.

Comment: @Quanto I did the integration by part, as shown in my post, I couldn't proceed. Can you give some hint?

Comment: @Quanto I’d be interested to see your derivation

Comment: @FShrike - The integrations of P and Q are still quite involved. I’ll type up when I get a chance

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**A (revolutionary) solution by Cornel Ioan Valean**

It is one of those integrals that are very resistant to the real methods and make you wonder if you ever can do anything to get a decent (real) solution! Well, with some amount of creativity it is possible to get a very elegant solution.
The integral is also included in the sequel of **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series** (an upcoming title).

Let's observe that by symmetry we have
$$I=\int _0^1\int _0^1\int _0^1\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)(1+z^2)(1+x^2 y^2 z^2)}dzdydx$$
$$=\frac{1}{3}\int _0^1\int _0^1\int _0^1\biggr(\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)(1+z^2)(1+x^2 y^2 z^2)}+\frac{y^2}{(1+y^2)(1+x^2)(1+x^2 y^2 z^2)}+\frac{z^2}{(1+z^2)(1+y^2)(1+x^2 y^2 z^2)}\biggr)dzdydx$$
$$\overset{\color{red}{\text{A key observation}}}{=}\frac{1}{3}\int _0^1\int _0^1\int _0^1\frac{\color{red}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)(1+z^2)-(1+x^2y^2z^2)}}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)(1+z^2)(1+x^2 y^2 z^2)}dzdydx$$
$$\small =\frac{1}{3}\biggr(\underbrace{\int _0^1\int _0^1\int _0^1\frac{dzdydx}{1+x^2 y^2 z^2}}_{\displaystyle \beta(3)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(2n-1)^3}=\pi^3/32}-\underbrace{\int _0^1\int _0^1\int _0^1\frac{dzdydx}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)(1+z^2)}\biggr)}_{\displaystyle \pi^3/64}=\frac{\pi^3}{192}.\tag1$$

On the other hand, we get
$$\small I=\int _0^1\int _0^1\int _0^1\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)(1+z^2)(1+x^2 y^2 z^2)}dzdydx=\int _0^1\int _0^1 \frac{x^2(\pi/4-x y\arctan(x y))}{(1+x^2)(1-x^2 y^2)}dydx$$
$$\overset{xy=t}{=}\int _0^1\int _0^x \frac{x(\pi/4-t\arctan(t))}{(1+x^2)(1-t^2)}dtdx=\int _0^1\int _t^1 \frac{x(\pi/4-t\arctan(t))}{(1+x^2)(1-t^2)}dxdt$$
$$=-\frac{\pi}{8}\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\log((1+t^2)/2)}{1-t^2}\textrm{d}t}_{\displaystyle -\pi^2/16}-\frac{1}{2}\color{blue}{\int_0^1 \frac{t\arctan(t) \log(2/(1+t^2))}{1-t^2}\textrm{d}t},\tag2$$
where the first integral after the last equal sign becomes trivial with the variable change $\displaystyle t\mapsto \frac{1-t}{1+t}$.

Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$, we arrive at the desired result,
$$\color{blue}{\int_0^1 \frac{t\arctan(t) \log(2/(1+t^2))}{1-t^2}\textrm{d}t=\frac{\pi^3}{192}}.$$

**End of story**

---

More details, more results (and connections to other tough integrals) involving such symmetry ideas in three dimensions will be found in the sequel of **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series**.

Here is a problem proposed by Cornel years ago in **RMM** that works great using such ideas as above
$$\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{(\tan^2(x)+\tan^2(y))\log(\tan(x))\log(\tan(y))\operatorname{Ti}_2(\tan(x) \tan(y))}{\tan(x)\tan(y)}\textrm{d}x\textrm{d}y$$
$$=\frac{1}{368640}\psi^5\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)-\frac{21}{32}\zeta(6)-\frac{2}{3}G^3,$$
where $\displaystyle \operatorname{Ti}_2(x)$ is the inverse tangent integral, $G$ represents the Catalan's constant, and $\psi^{(n)}$ denotes the Polygamma function.

Comment: Awesome solution! How can this be constructed?! I mean how to start from that blue-color integral to find such a symmetry construction, too amazing! or maybe they begin with that 3D integral and finally find this byproduct integral in blue color?

Comment: @GGplay In this particular case, the extraction started from the investigation of the special multiple integral. However, depending on the context, it may be way more challenging, but at the same time very exciting, to explore ways of transforming a single integral to a useful multiple integral that to further calculated by means of symmetry or other creative ways. Doing this is ART, and very possible with much work, practice!

Comment: This solution made the question look so trivial. Congrats on such beauty!! (+1)

Comment: @AliShadhar Thank you so much, Ali! :-)

Comment: what is "revolutinary" about this method? evaluating double integrals in two different ways is clever but by no means groundbreaking. Here a nice example where this technique is employed: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2454168/proving-left1-frac13-frac15-frac17-cdots-right2-frac38-left-frac112

Comment: @cauchyscrazychick The creativity lies not in solving that triple integral, but in picking such integral and related it to the wanted integral and extrat its result in a very simple way. Absolutely revolutionary.

Comment: @AliShadhar we agree to disagree. IMHO this is just clever , nothing really new here.

Comment: @user97357329 Thank you so much and I choose this answer :)

Comment: Hi sir! Are you Cornel Ioan Valean?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a more general solution. Use the contour setup by [Sangchul Lee](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/411763/686284), it can be shown that

$$\int_0^1 \frac{x \arctan a x}{1-x^2}\ln\frac{1+a^2}{1+a^2x^2}dx=\frac13 \arctan^3 a
$$
Let $a=1$ to obtain
$$\int_0^1 \frac{x \arctan x}{1-x^2}\ln\frac{2}{1+x^2}dx=\frac13 \arctan^3 (1)=\frac{\pi^3}{192}
$$

Comment: thank you! Is there a way to solve it without using contour integrals?

Comment: @GGplay - You can integrate P and Q using elementary techniques, which are quite lengthy

Comment: @GGplay - see, for example, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/542741/686284

Comment: @Quanto I like the beauty of contour integrations but frankly my skill in practical integration is not very high... how elementary are you talking? Can P and Q be integrated -by-parts and substituted (at length) and that suffices? Or would one need to introduce some series manipulations or regularisation techniques etc.

Comment: @FShrike - Q is linked above and P can be split into
$$2P=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1-x^2)}{1+x^2}dx+ \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2\frac{1+x^2}{2}}{1+x^2}dx+ -\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2\frac{2(1-x^2)}{1+x^2}}{1+x^2}dx
$$