Closed form for square inverse tangent integral $\int\limits_0^1 {\frac{{{{\arctan }^2}\left( {\frac{x}{{1 - {x^2}}}} \right)}}{x}dx}$
I am trying to evaluate this integral:$$K = \displaystyle \int\limits_0^1 {\frac{{{{\arctan }^2}\left( {\frac{x}{{1 - {x^2}}}} \right)}}{x}dx}$$
And here is my attempt so far:
$$\begin{align}
  K&=\int\limits_0^1 {\frac{{{{\arctan }^2}\left( {\frac{x}{{1 - {x^2}}}} \right)}}{x}dx} \xrightarrow{{{\text{IBP}}}} - 2\int\limits_0^1 {\frac{{\left( {{x^2} + 1} \right)\arctan \left( {\frac{x}{{1 - {x^2}}}} \right)\ln \left( x \right)}}{{{x^4} - {x^2} + 1}}dx}\\&=  - 2\int\limits_0^1 {\frac{{{x^2}\arctan \left( {\frac{x}{{1 - {x^2}}}} \right)\ln \left( x \right)}}{{{x^4} - {x^2} + 1}}dx}  - 2\int\limits_0^1 {\frac{{\arctan \left( {\frac{x}{{1 - {x^2}}}} \right)\ln \left( x \right)}}{{{x^4} - {x^2} + 1}}dx}  \hfill \\
   \\&=- 2\int\limits_0^1 {\frac{{{x^2}\arctan \left( {\frac{x}{{1 - {x^2}}}} \right)\ln \left( x \right)}}{{{x^4} - {x^2} + 1}}dx}  - 2\int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{{\arctan \left( {\frac{x}{{1 - {x^2}}}} \right)\ln \left( x \right)}}{{{x^4} - {x^2} + 1}}dx}  \\&\quad\quad+ 2\underbrace {\int\limits_1^\infty  {\frac{{\arctan \left( {\frac{x}{{1 - {x^2}}}} \right)\ln \left( x \right)}}{{{x^4} - {x^2} + 1}}dx} }_{x \to \frac{1}{x}} \\&=  - 2\int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{{\arctan \left( {\frac{x}{{1 - {x^2}}}} \right)\ln \left( x \right)}}{{{x^4} - {x^2} + 1}}dx}  \hfill \\ 
\end{align}$$
The last integral seems can be evaluated by using complex integration technique. But I don't know how to use it. And can I ask for help or another approach? Thank you so much.
The closed form for $K$ is: $$K=\frac{4\pi}{3}\cdot G-\frac{35}{36}\cdot\zeta(3)-\frac{5\pi}{36\sqrt{3}}(\psi'(1/3)-\psi'(2/3))$$

Similar question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4405138/how-to-prove-int-01-frac-arctan2x-ln-left-fracx1-x2-rightx?rq=1

@Zima In fact, there is closed form for this integral.

@ErikSatie Thank you for your suggestion. But these 2 problem are different too much.

@Zima $$\frac{4 \pi  G}{3}-\frac{35 \zeta (3)}{36}-\frac{5 \pi  \left(\psi ^{(1)}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)-\psi ^{(1)}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)\right)}{36 \sqrt{3}}$$. Thank you.

The integral is equivalent to $$\frac{\pi^2}{4}\log2+\frac74 \zeta(3)-2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}t \log(\sqrt{4\tan^2 t+1}-1) dt$$

Did you learn this closed form from a CAS?

@FShrike This problem came from my friend, but i could only solve at the last integral in my post. After stucking then i ask him the closed form, and he gave me without a hint. Thank you for your comment.

@user170231 No, the last line is correct (numerically too, if you don't believe me)

@FShrike You're right, I was mistaken!

The integral J is what you are looking for You may want to consider this (remember that it is not my solution):
https://www.facebook.com/groups/170225716325580/permalink/6514069418607813/?app=fbl
